# Change entry Border color using Custom Renderers in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

`I have used custom renderer class and i am able to change the border color. Now on click of a button i want to reset it again`. I tried to reset it on click of a buttom but it's not working for both iOS and Android.

```
       .xaml file

       <local:BorderedEntryRenderer x:Name="NameEntry"
                     HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"
                     WidthRequest="210"
                     Text="{Binding ProfileName}" BorderColor="Chocolate" />


       .cs file

         public void EditProfile_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {
            NameEntry.BorderColor = Color.Blue; //to reset the color on click
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO !

If want to use custom renderer for `Entry` in Xamarin Forms , you can have a look at this document first (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)

Here if need to change border color of `Entry` ,  actually need to use custom renderer to achieve that .

Create a custom `Entry` in Forms .

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
}
```

Used in **Xaml** :

```
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomRenderer;assembly=CustomRenderer"
    ...>
    ...
    <local:MyEntry Text="In Shared Code" />
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Then in **iOS** solution , need to create a renderer class(such as `CustomEntryRenderer`) :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.iOS
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer,IUITextFieldDelegate
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Also in **Android** solution , need to create a custom renderer class :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.Android{
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
            var shape = new ShapeDrawable(new Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape());
            shape.Paint.Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red.ToAndroid();
            shape.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            nativeEditText.Background = shape;
        }
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image][image]

=============================Update===============================

If want to use event to control the border of `Entry` , we can use **[MessageCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)** to achieve that .

For example , we can create two buttons in **Xaml** to add two clicked method to control the border of `Entry` .

```
<Button Text="SetBorder" Clicked="Button_Clicked_setborder"/>
<Button Text="Reset" Clicked="Button_Clicked_reset"/>
```

The implement of each clicked method is :

```
private void Button_Clicked_setborder(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<object,bool>(this,"Hi",true);
}

private void Button_Clicked_reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, bool>(this, "Hi", false);
}
```

Then in the **iOS** entry renderer class , modified as follow :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.iOS
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer,IUITextFieldDelegate
    {

        CoreGraphics.CGColor defaultBorderColor;
        nfloat defaultBorderWidth;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            defaultBorderColor = Control.Layer.BorderColor;
            defaultBorderWidth = Control.Layer.BorderWidth;


            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, bool>(this, "Hi", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
                Console.WriteLine("Hi , I have received this");
                if (arg)
                {
                    Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
                    Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Control.Layer.BorderColor = defaultBorderColor;
                    Control.Layer.BorderWidth = defaultBorderWidth;
                }

            });

          
        }

    }
}
```

The same modified in **Android** renderer class :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.Droid
{
    [Obsolete]
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        Drawable defaultTextBackgroundColor;
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            
            defaultTextBackgroundColor = Control.Background;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object,bool>(this, "Hi", (sender,arg) =>
            {
                // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
                Console.WriteLine("Hi , I have received this");
                if (arg)
                {
                    var shape = new ShapeDrawable(new Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape());
                    shape.Paint.Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red.ToAndroid();
                    shape.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
                    Control.Background = shape;
                }
                else
                {
                    Control.Background = defaultTextBackgroundColor;
                }
           
            });

        }

    }
}
```

The effect :

[image: iOS effect]
[image: Android effect]

Comment: i have used all these things and with the help of custom renderer, i am able to change border color for entry , now i want to reset it again on click of a button that i am not able to do

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni Okey , I guess maybe you want the `Entry` be *focused* show the border , and *unfocused* show the default style . If so , I will update the answer .

Comment: the idea is once user navigates to this screen, border color for entry should be of faded color and in the same screen we have edit profile icon, once user selects that icon, border color for entry should change to something bright. Is it possible - (Nothing related to focusing on an entry)- color should change on click of an imagebutton.

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni Okey , got that . I will check that whether it possible in Xamarin Forms .

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni We can use **MessageCenter** to achieve that , I will update answer .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should checkout [Xamarin Forms Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers).

using triggers you will be able to fire up events from actions or states.
It also helps u to keep everything organized in the xaml file without the need for the code behind.